# JSON file conflict in IOS Project

Tags: objective-c, ios, json

I'm using both a Google Places API and a Facebook iOS SDK API in an iOS project. Both API's come with JSON files that are causing a conflict. What's the best way to handle this?

the error is: "duplicate interface definition for class 'SBJsonParser'"

this is after adding the Facebook api. Could they both use the same JSON files?

thanks for any help.

Comment: You need to give some more information. What is the conflict? A conflict in the sense that you're getting values from each that don't make sense (i.e. 1 + 1 = 2 VS 1 + 1 = 3), or some sort of internal inconsistency conflict?

Comment: Both the same library? FB uses SBJSON I think right? Same for Google Places?

Comment: conflicts as in "duplicate interface definition for class 'SBJsonParser'"

Comment: If you can target iOS 5.0 and later only, you can use the inbuilt support for JSON, rather than the SBJsonParser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have two copies of the SBJSON files in your project. These were probably imported for both Google and Facebook.

You will need to remove one copy of the files. Both Google and Facebook should happily use a single set of files, but of course you should test to be sure!

Comment: yes. that's right. I have two copies. the problem is that I'm running into the following error: duplicate interface definition for class 'SBJsonParser'"

Comment: As I mention, you should be able to remove one of the copies, and both will use the one remaining copy. (I would suggest that you check the version numbers of both copies, keep the latest version, and do some thorough testing)

Comment: I still can't seem to figure this out. removing the duplicates isn't working and runs into other errors like about linking the Facebook SDK properly.

Comment: Ensure you have removed the JSON group only. Has the original error been resolved? i.e. "duplicate interface definition for class 'SBJsonParser'". If so, this may be a different problem.

Comment: after removing only the JSON group I'm getting the: clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Whatto-gtjwoowlzxtnndfpmiqjacvnbtxw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libfacebook_ios_sdk.a' error